# Why does a member function invocation not infer a required receiver from the calling function?

Tags: kotlin

Consider:

```
class Foo {
    fun CoroutineScope.foo() {

    }
}

class Bar {
    val f = Foo()

    fun CoroutineScope.bar() { // this could also be "suspend fun bar = coroutineScope {"
        f.foo() // unresolved reference

        with (f) { 
            foo() // OK
        }

        with (f) {
            with(this) {
                foo() // OK
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

It seems like the first attempt at `f.foo()` should infer the `CoroutineScope` receiver specified on `bar()`. It seems it doesn't; but in an attempt to understand receivers better, does anyone have an explanation as to *why*?

**Edit**

([Playground link](https://pl.kotl.in/tadqRb904))

After looking over [some docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) (specifically the *"Declaring extensions as members"*) and Rene's response, I tried a few more things:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class Foo {
    fun CoroutineScope.foo() { println("Foo.foo")}
    fun Baz.fed(){ println("Foo.fed") }
}

class Baz {
    fun CoroutineScope.foo() { println("Baz.foo") }
    fun Foo.fed(){ println("Baz.fed") }
}

fun CoroutineScope.foo() { println("CoroutineScope.foo") }

fun foo() { println("Global.foo") }

fun bar(scope: CoroutineScope) {
    val f = Foo()
    val b = Baz()

    println ("Test 1")
    foo() // foo() from Global
    scope.foo() // foo() from CoroutineScope
    //f.foo() // unresolved reference

    println ("\nTest 2")
    with(scope) {
        foo() // foo() from CoroutineScope
        //f.foo() // unresolved reference
    }

    println ("\nTest 3")
    with(f) {
        scope.foo() // foo() from Foo
        foo() // foo() from Global
    }

    println ("\nTest 4")
    with(scope) {
        with (f) {
            foo() // foo() from Foo
            scope.foo() // foo() from Foo
        }
    }

    println ("\nTest 5")
    with(f) {
        with (scope) {
            foo() // foo() from Foo
            scope.foo() // foo() from Foo
        }
    }

    println ("\nTest 6")
    with(b) {
        with(f) {
            with (scope) {
                foo() // foo() from Foo

                fed() // fed() from Baz     
            }
        }
    }

    println ("\nTest 7")
    with(f) {
        with(b) {
            with (scope) {
                foo() // foo() from Baz

                fed() // fed() from Foo
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    bar(this)
}
```

It's interesting to see that when both contexts are made available via `with`, it is able to figure out which one is the *dispatch context* and which the *extension context*, regardless of what order they are provided. But if you specify the *extension context* directly like `f.bar()`, it will *only* look for versions of `bar` with *extension receiver* of type `Foo`, or a direct member of `Foo` (I'm still a bit hazy about how it views *dispatch* and *extension* receivers for a function that is simply defined in the class definition). So it seems the logic is something like:

Given expression `x.y()`:

1. Find all functions `y()` that take *extension receiver* `x`
2. For each receiver available `c`, starting with the most recently added, choose the first `x.y()` that **explicitly** takes a *dispatch receiver* of type `c` - note that `fun CoroutineScope.foo()` in global scope acts like it has no *dispatch receiver*, since tests 6 and 7 show that even though `scope` is added to the available context list last, `Foo` (or `Baz`) version of `foo()` is used.

Given expression `y()`:

1. Try to find an `x.y()` with both a *dispatch receiver* and *extension receiver* (x) defined and in the list of available contexts. (note: it chooses the most recently added *extension receiver* first, then tries to find a matching *dispatch receiver* (see test 6 and 7 with `fed()`)
2. If #1 returned nothing, choose most recently added context with *dispatch receiver* `x` in available contexts that define function `y()`
3. Still nothing? Choose the most recently added context with *extension receiver* `x` that define function `y()`
4. Fall back to global version of `y()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration:

```
class Foo {
    fun CoroutineScope.foo() {

    }
}
```

defines an extension function `foo` of `CoroutineScope` in the context of an instance of the class `Foo`. This means you can only invoke `foo` on an instance of `CoroutineScope` if you are in a scope where `this` is of the type `Foo`.

The first attempt `f.foo()` does exactly the opposite. You invoke `foo()` on an instance of `Foo`  and `this` references a `CoroutineScope`.

The two other examples uses `with` to set the `this` reference to `Foo` and therefor you can invoke `foo` on the outer `CoroutineScope` instance.

BTW: `with(this)`  makes no sense, because `this` will be set to `this`.